# React - Render dropdown list to two separate dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Working in React i have two different downs created (using one state). At the moment if i change countries on one the city list changes on both the selected option and that's causing issues. If i choose say UK and choose a city(London) in the Europe box then the city list on the Asia box also changes to that city(London) and vice versa. How can i got about resolving this issue so if one selected the other has no impact on it. Thanks:

```
`function DisplayDifferentLocation({ searchCities }) {
  const [city, setCity] = useState(null);
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");

  const getWeatherData = (selectedCity) => {
    if (selectedCity) {
      const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${selectedCity}&units=metric&appid=08acd577f8ab8cabf637f7cd3736a629`;
      axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        setWeatherData(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {}, [searchCities]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setCity(event.target.value);
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleChange1 = (event1) => {
    console.log(event1.target.value);
    setCity(event1.target.value);
    setValue(event1.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (city) {
      setIsLoading(true);
      getWeatherData(city);
    }
  }, [city]);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {};


  const changeSelectOptionHandler = (event) => {
    setSelected(event.target.value);
  };

  const changeSelectOptionHandler1 = (event1) => {
    setSelected(event1.target.value);
  };
//Europe
  const UK = ["Choose City", "London", "Manchester", "Birmingham", "Glasgow"];
  const France = ["Choose City", "Paris", "Calais", "Lyon", "Nice"];
  const Spain = ["Choose City", "Barcelona", "Madrid", "Córdoba", "Seville "];

  //Asia
  const China = ["Choose City", "Beijing", "Shanghai", "Hong Kong", "Macau"];
  const India = ["Choose City", "Delhi", "Chennai", "Madras", "Luknow"];
  const Kazakhstan = ["Choose City", "Astana", "Almaty", "Shymkent", "Atau"];

  /** Type variable to store different array for different dropdown */
  let type = null;

  /** This will be used to create set of options that user will see */
  let options = null;

  if (selected === "UK") {
    type = UK;
  } else if (selected === "France") {
    type = France;
  } else if (selected === "Spain") {
    type = Spain;
  }else if (selected === "Kazakhstan") {
    type = Kazakhstan;
  }else if (selected === "India") {
    type = India;
  }else if (selected === "China") {
    type = China;
  }

  if (type) {
    options = type.map((el) => <option key={el}>{el}</option>);
  }

  const getInitialState = () => {
    const value = "No City";
    return value;
  };

  const [value, setValue] = useState(getInitialState);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <h2>Still Loading be patient</h2>;
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="page">
        <div className="europe">
          <ul>
            <p1 style={{fontSize:32}}>Europe</p1>
            <select onChange={changeSelectOptionHandler}>
              <option>Choose Country</option>
              <option>UK</option>
              <option>France</option>
              <option>Spain</option>
            </select>
            <p>
              <select name="city" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
                {
                  /** This is where we have used our options variable */
                  options
                }
              </select>
            </p>
           <p className="city"> City:{` ${value}`}</p>
           <br></br>
            <p>Humidity: {weatherData?.main.humidity}</p>
            <p>Temp: {weatherData?.main.temp}</p>
            <p>Feels Like: {weatherData?.main.feels_like}</p>
            <p>Wind: {weatherData?.wind.speed}</p>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="asia">
          <ul>
            <p style={{fontSize:32}}>Asia</p>
            <select onChange={changeSelectOptionHandler1}>
              <option>Choose Country</option>
              <option>China</option>
              <option>India</option>
              <option>Kazakhstan</option>
            </select>
            <p>
              <select name="city2" value={value} onChange={handleChange1}>
                {
                  /** This is where we have used our options variable */
                  options
                }
              </select>
            </p>
           <p className="city2"> City:{` ${value}`}</p>
           <br></br>
            <p>Humidity: {weatherData?.main.humidity}</p>
            <p>Temp: {weatherData?.main.temp}</p>
            <p>Feels Like: {weatherData?.main.feels_like}</p>
            <p>Wind: {weatherData?.wind.speed}</p>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default DisplayDifferentLocation;
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're managing the component state for `city`, `weatherData` and `selected` in one variable shared between the two dropdowns, so whenever you set the state you're updating it for both of them. You need to separate the state management for the two components.

The React way to do this would be to create a reusable Dropdown component that you use for each dropdown so the state is managed separately. Then you could also avoid having to create duplicate event handlers like `changeSelectOptionHandler` and `changeSelectOption Handler1`. Try something like this. Here is a code sandbox with the code working: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-snowflake-k05kwn?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <Dropdown title="Europe" options={["UK", "France", "Spain"]} />
      <Dropdown title="Asia" options={["China", "India", "Kazakhstan"]} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Dropdown({ title, options, searchCities }) {
  const [city, setCity] = useState(null);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState();
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("city", city);
    if (city) {
      const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=08acd577f8ab8cabf637f7cd3736a629`;

      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((jsonResponse) => {
          console.log("jsonResponse", jsonResponse);
          setWeatherData(jsonResponse);
          console.log("jsonResponse data", jsonResponse.main);
        });
    }
  }, [city]);

  const cities = {
    UK: ["London", "Manchester", "Birmingham", "Glasgow"],
    France: ["Paris", "Calais", "Lyon", "Nice"],
    Spain: ["Barcelona", "Madrid", "Córdoba", "Seville "],
    China: ["Beijing", "Shanghai", "Hong Kong", "Macau"],
    India: ["Delhi", "Chennai", "Madras", "Luknow"],
    Kazakhstan: ["Astana", "Almaty", "Shymkent", "Atau"]
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setCity(event.target.value);
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const getInitialState = () => {
    const value = "No City";
    return value;
  };

  const [value, setValue] = useState(getInitialState);

  return (
    <div className={title}>
      <h1 style={{ fontSize: 32, width: "100%" }}>{title}</h1>
      <select onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}>
        <option>Choose Country</option>
        {options?.map((opt) => (
          <option value={opt} key={opt}>
            {opt}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <p>
        <select name="city" value={city} onChange={handleChange}>
          <option key="choose city">Choose City</option>
          {cities[country]?.map((c) => (
            <option value={c} key={c}>
              {c}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </p>
      <p className="city"> City:{` ${value}`}</p>
      <br></br>
      <p>Humidity: {weatherData?.main?.humidity}</p>
      <p>Temp: {weatherData?.main?.temp}</p>
      <p>Feels Like: {weatherData?.main?.feels_like}</p>
      <p>Wind: {weatherData?.wind?.speed}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could continue to refactor and improve this (e.g., combine the country and city names into one object), but it should give you the right idea for how to create a reusable component that manages its own state. This will allow you to manage the state for the two dropdowns separately and de-duplicate a lot of the current logic.

Comment: Drop down list not populating...code attached above

Comment: @MahmudChoudhury: I've updated the answer above to fill out the code now so it's working for you in the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-snowflake-k05kwn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you very much. Before taking it i'm going through and trying to under how it working and what's triggering what (no point copying without learning) - anyway very appreciative of your responses